# StoredProcedure not workng correctly

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

What I am doing here is I am updating my records when my record_id=0 and activity_id=0 condition fails..But what result I am getting is It is updating all the records regardless of the condition **WHERE activity_id = Activity_ID**  (in Update tms_activity Line)

This is he procedure I wrote in MySql

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `EmpTimeSheet_SaveTasks`(IN user_ID INT(11),
    IN date DATE,
    IN record_ID INT(11),
    IN task_ID INT(10),
    IN Hours double,
    IN Description longtext,
    IN Updated_By_ID INT(11),
    IN Project_ID INT(11),
    IN Project_Name Varchar(50),
    IN Task_Name Varchar(50),
    IN Activity_ID INT(11),
    IN Deleted_ID Varchar(100)
    )
    BEGIN
     IF record_ID = 0 THEN

     INSERT IGNORE INTO tms_timesheet(user_id, date, is_freezed)  VALUES (user_ID,date,0);
     SET @ID = (SELECT record_id FROM tms_timesheet WHERE user_id= user_ID  and date=date);
     INSERT INTO tms_activity (timesheet_id, task_id, hours, description, updated_on, updated_by_id,project_id,project_name,task_name )  VALUES (@ID ,task_ID,Hours ,Description, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP( ) ,user_ID,Project_ID,Project_Name ,Task_Name );

     ELSE IF Activity_ID = 0 THEN

    INSERT INTO tms_activity ( timesheet_id, task_id, hours, description, updated_on, updated_by_id,project_id,project_name,task_name )  VALUES (record_ID ,task_ID,Hours ,Description, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP( ) ,user_ID, Project_ID ,Project_Name,Task_Name);

    ELSE

         UPDATE tms_activity  SET  task_id=task_ID, hours=Hours, description=Description, updated_on=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP( ),    updated_by_id=user_ID,project_id=Project_ID,task_name=Task_Name,project_name=Project_Name *****WHERE activity_id = Activity_ID;*****
     END IF;

     END IF;

    IF Deleted_ID!='' THEN

     DELETE FROM tms_activity where activity_id in (Deleted_ID);

    END IF;

    END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself actually the solution was quiet weird for me because when I changed my parameter name from **Activity_ID** to **ActivityID**,It WORKED..I dont know the reason how It happened and WHy..But it solved my error

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is  the var name.
Try to changing "Activity_ID" to "vActivity_ID".